# No se puede iniciar la sesión cuando los encabezados ya se enviaron php

Tags: php

Tengo el siguiente problema en algunos de las paginas de la web, lo raro es que todas están configuradas de la mismas forma y que en el servidor local si funcionan pero en el servidor publico no.

Error:

> PHP Warning:  session_start(): Cannot start session when headers already sent in /home3/nesitelc/nes.nesitelco.com/admin/at/aprobar.php on line 3

Código inicial:

```
<?php
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION["id_usuario"])){ //Si no ha iniciado sesión redirecciona a index.php
  header("Location: ../index.php");
}
if(!isset($_GET['id'])){
  header("Location: ./pendientes.php");
}
```

Comment: `session_start()` tiene que ser la primera línea del php, antes de enviar cualquier header se tiene que hacer `session_start()`

Comment: Me acabo de fijar que la linea 1 era un salto de lineal y estaba vacía, el error era eso, gracias.

Answer (score 1):

El problema que aquí ocurre está claramente descrito en la primera **Nota** del Manual de PHP sobre [`session_start()`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.session-start.php):

> Para usar sesiones basadas en cookies, `session_start()` debe ser
> llamada antes de imprimir cualquier cosa en el navegador.

Por *imprimir cualquier cosa en el navegador* entiéndase **cualquier cosa**, desde líneas en blanco, bloques HTML, salidas explícitas por pantalla con `echo, print, var_dump`, etc.

Eso debe tenerse en cuenta no sólo con respecto al archivo actual, sino con todos los archivos que estén en ese contexto o flujo, como podrían ser archivos incluidos o requeridos. Si cualquiera de ellos tiene algún tipo de salida por pantalla ocurrirá este problema.

Hay que evitar también que haya [caracteres BOM](https://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-byte-order-mark), los cuales provocarán el mismo error. Hoy día casi todos los editores de código traen herramientas para limpiar el código de estos caracteres o para mostrarlos.

Esto es así porque, como también dice el Manual de PHP en la tercera **Nota**:

> Esta función envía varias cabeceras HTTP dependiendo de la
> configuración.

Y, antes de las cabeceras, no puede haber ninguna salida por pantalla, como bien explica el Manual de PHP al hablar sobre [`header()`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.header.php):

> Recuerde que `header()` debe ser llamado antes de mostrar nada por
> pantalla, etiquetas HTML, líneas en blanco desde un fichero o desde
> PHP. Es un error muy común leer código con funciones como `include` o
> `require`, u otro tipo de funciones de acceso de ficheros que incluyen
> espacios o líneas en blanco que se muestran antes de llamar a la
> función `header()`. Sucede el mismo problema cuando se utiliza un solo
> fichero PHP/HTML.

Guarda en mente esto también con respecto a `header()`, porque es un error muy extendido usar `header()` sin un control estricto de lo que sale por pantalla, provocando una situación igual a la que te está ocurriendo con `session_start()`.

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta @A. Cedano, mas claro no pudo quedar.